# Forcing page-speed insights to rescan my page

Tags: google, html, bugs, google-pagespeed

I'm trying to get google to rescan my page at page-speed insights. After the initial scan, I get results along with the following at the bottom:

> *The results are cached for 30s. If you have made changes to your page, please wait for 30s before re-running the test.

I updated my site since the first test to add an HTML element inside the DIV it was complaining about. The caching of the HTML is always set to off with connection set to close.

So at least a couple minutes go by and then I run the test again only to find the same issues come up.

How is that even possible when google states they only require a 30 second waiting time to rerun the same test?

**And to further complicate things...**

I did the exact same test just now both on the mobile friendly test page at google and page-speed insights. On the mobile friendly test page, I got word that the page is mobile friendly, and on page-speed insights, the exact same error appeared AGAIN!

Comment: I like to swear and shake a fist and sometimes a finger (never mind which one). When this does not work, then I go to the kitchen and get a snack. That usually does the trick. BTW- I need to lose weight. You should know by now that Google is designed to frustrate us dweebs by not doing what they say. Google is becoming Microsoft 2.0.

Comment: don't forget to put +1 to the guy who posted all thoose links, else people won't share anymore...

Answer (score 1):

on my test of this issue i got Google to immediately show correct (current) version of the site, if i run the Speedtest from within incognito window (and not logged in into google account)

Answer (score 0):

Google page speed insight works well, i tested it a lot. Right now i just made a test and when i restarted tests results was updated.
You can try to clear your browser cache or use another browser, but what is sure it doesn't come from Google.
Or maybe your website changes wasn't enought concluant.